# How to expand div height to bottom with css?

Tags: html, height, expand

I have a div container in my html page and i want set its height to expand all remaining page in the screen..

How can i do that ??

That's my code :

HTML

```
<div class="row">
       <div id="builder-container" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9">                                    
             <div id="builder-content"  > </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#builder-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to give all of the parent elements, including the div you want to extend, a height of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would not get cover your whole page without enough content, but the best way is to give it 'position:absolute/fixed/relative' and give the same div top:whateveryouwant px; and bottom: 0px/0%; width and height :100%

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25xs7b4w/5/) - **Edited: Check it now**

**CSS**

```
    body
{
   margin:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

    #builder-container {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:5%;
        left:0%;
        bottom:0%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: the problem how can i calculate the above content to give a proper value for top? is there any automatic trick ?

Comment: am not getting what you trying to say

Comment: I mean this div don't start from the top beginning. There is a content above it so i want to get beginning after this content

Comment: Ok so you saying that there is some div above this row ? I would suggest you to show the code of above div so its easy for people here to solve the problem, because by this half code no one would able to solve the problem

Comment: I have edited the above JSFiddle link, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

## html

```
<div class="row full_height">
    <h1>Test elem</h1>
</div>
```

## css

```
.full_height {
    height: 100vh
}
```